# NodeJS Converting Unicode to JPG

Tags: node.js, image, unicode

I am pretty new to image conversion and trying to figure a way out on how to convert this chunk of data to a JPG file. Is is even possible?

This is the chunk

[image]

Is there any node modules I can use to convert this

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sending an image in header? I would suggest you otherwise. Also, how you're converting it to whatever type of data it is. I'm pretty sure that's not base64.

Comment: make use of `fs` module

Comment: @Prajwal. Nope it's coming from a TCP port of a device.